# Tracking Social Tweets on Website with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk

We have a website which holds a Twitter Tweet button. We are looking to track the social events for clicking on the tweet button.

We are using the newer Universal Analytics and following this example:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/social-interactions

For twitter we include their JS as follows:

```
<script async defer>
!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
</script>
```

We are having issues binding to the tweet event as described on Twitter here:
https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/events

The issue is that 'twttr is not defined'. There is a similar question on SO here: 
[ReferenceError: "twttr is not defined" even while using twttr.ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550328/referenceerror-twttr-is-not-defined-even-while-using-twttr-ready)

I have tried to implement the same approach here, but I am not getting any of the console logs appear?

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    document.getElementById('twitter-wjs').addEventListener('load', function() {
      console.log('1');
        twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
          console.log('2');
            twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(e){
              console.log('3');
                if(!e) return;
                ga('send', 'social', 'twitter', 'tweet', theURL);
                console.log('tweet');
            })
        });
    }, false);
}, false);
</script>
```

How can we track the Twitter Tweet clicks in GA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're adding a `load` event handler for the Twitter widget script inside the `window` object's `load` event callback. If the Twitter widget's script code is part of the page's initial content, then the browser will download that script and run it before firing the `window`'s `load` event.

In other words, you script's `load` handler is never running because its `load` event has already happened -- before you added the listener for it.

You can update your code to check if the `twttr` object is there prior to adding the `load` listener for the script:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {

  function onTwttrReady() {
    twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(e){
      if(!e) return;
      ga('send', 'social', 'twitter', 'tweet', theURL);
      console.log('tweet');
    })
  }

  if (window.twttr) {
    onTwttrReady();
  } else {
    document.getElementById('twitter-wjs')
            .addEventListener('load', onTwttrReady);
  }
});
```

Comment: Just to follow on from this I used your post - http://philipwalton.com/articles/stop-copying-social-code-snippets/ - To improve my social networking code a lot, thanks for this.