# HTML Twitter Widget displays on local dev site, but not when I upload to live site

Tags: html, twitter

I have embedded the twitter widget using the code provided in the twitter dev page into the footer of my site (HTML, not wordpress).

Locally it displays without any issues (see image attached).

[what it looks like locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgugr.png)

However when I upload the page to the development site online it only shows a [link](http://webheroesdevsite.com/Robur/index.html) to the account:

Any ideas why this may be? Is it some widget issue because I have embedded it into 2 versions of the site?

cheers in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, adding a call to `twttr.widgets.load()` at the end of the widget solved it for me.

Comment: are you adding this to the script function?

Comment: @DavidOak Yes, for example: `<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs"); twttr.widgets.load();</script>`

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have tried as you suggested but no joy. Chrome is now throwing up the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: twttr is not defined" on my line of code. Any ideas? This is my script code      <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs"); twttr.widgets.load();</script>

Comment: This person's [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550328/referenceerror-twttr-is-not-defined-even-while-using-twttr-ready) may be of help.